# Primefaces css overrides custom css

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

```
.ui-orderlist .ui-orderlist-list {
    height: auto;
}
```

Should't it set height of list to auto? Because it does't work.
In browser styles appears like

```
.ui-orderlist .ui-orderlist-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.ui-orderlist .ui-orderlist-list {
    height: auto; // this line no active
}
```

Comment: You could give it a styleClass property and fix it in the CSS file. Is also better for maintenance

Comment: no mater how to define it

Comment: but that makes it an CSS issue, not a JSF issue ;-)

Comment: I'm not a CSS guru, adding !important  ( height: auto !important; ) should make the css line always active. Better solution is to have a correct order of CSS files loading in the header.

Comment: @WvdL well, it works. the header contains only custom styles.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same issue some days ago. You have to make sure that your stylesheet gets loaded after default PrimeFaces CSS. You can achieve this by including your stylesheet in the following way:

```
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="last">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/yourstyle.css"></link>
    </f:facet>
</h:head>
```

PS: Please do not use `!important`.

Comment: This is PART of the answer, see the duplicate

Comment: I can't see my answer anywhere in the question referenced as duplicate.

Comment: Uhhmmmm… . the very first paragraph?    **Load your CSS after PrimeFaces one**

Answer (score 0):

You can override css rules by making them more specific than default primefaces rules and thus giving more "weight" for your custom rule. For example, wrap your order list with a `< div class="some_class">< p:orderList ... />< /div>` and provide css rule like:

```
div.some_class .ui-orderlist .ui-orderlist-list {
    height: auto;
}
```

You can read more about css specificity [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity).

Alternatively you could add an `!important` exception to your custom rule like:

```
.ui-orderlist .ui-orderlist-list {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Such approach though is not recommended and should be used (as mentioned @Kukeltje in comment) as the last choice.

Comment: I'd switch the !important and specificity order in the post. Important should be a last resort

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion. Reordered.